# Forcing mono print on a colour printer with CUPS?

Tags: cups

I have been instructed to create 2 print queues on one MFD, one colour and one mono.

I have installed CUPS on Ubuntu 18.04LTS and can print from a Win 10 machine (client) using http://printserver/printername

The mono print queue is the problem - how do I convert colour print jobs to mono?

TIA,

Mat

Comment: As far as I know you don’t convert color to grey scale on a print server , you advertise the printer / queue as B&W and the clients will send a print job directly in grey scale...  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/386043/48232

Comment: Thanks - cups now complains of duplicate profiles even when they've been deleted (eg CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id \'RICOH_MP_C3004_MONO1-Gray). It's a long way from a simple solution - and it stil prints test pages in colour despite a tweaked PPD file (as per link).